# Find all real numbers $a$ for equation $x^3 + ax^2 + 51x + 2023=0$, has two equal roots.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, cubics, roots-of-cubics

**Problem:**

Find all real numbers $a$ for which the equation, $x^3 + ax^2 + 51x + 2023=0$, has two equal roots.

- This problem is from an algebra round of a local high school math competition that has already ended

**My Work:**

To find when $x^3 + ax^2 + 51x + 2023$ has two equal roots, we can use the properties of the discriminant. For a cubic polynomial, the discriminant is given by the following formula:

$Δ = 18abcd - 4b^3d + b^2c^2 - 4ac^3 - 27a^2d^2$

In our case, the cubic polynomial is $x^3 + ax^2 + 51x + 2023$, so $a = 1$, $b = a$, $c = 51$, and $d = 2023$.

If the polynomial has two equal roots, its discriminant must be equal to zero. So, we can set Δ equal to zero and solve for a:

$0 = 18(1)(a)(51)(2023) - 4a^3(2023) + a^2(51)^2 - 4(1)(51)^3 - 27(1)^2(2023)^2$

However, after this step, I am really stuck. I would appreciate some help! Thank you!

Comment: @CalvinLin  I have posted an answer, starting from my former comment, which I believe shows that there _is_ only the integer solution if $ \ a \ $ is to be real.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Proceeding in a different manner as I don't see a realistic way to complete your solution in a high school competition setting.)

We have $x^3 + ax^2 + 51x + 2023 = (x+b)^2(x+c)$.
By comparing coefficients,

- $ a = 2b + c$
- $ 2bc + b^2 = 51$
- $ b^2c = 2023$

Substitute $ c = \frac{2023}{b^2}$ to eliminate it, we get $ 51 b = b(b^2 + 2bc) = b^3 + 2\times 2023$.
Facotorizing this cubic (start by testing the factors of 4046), we get $0 = (b+17) ( b^2 - 17b + 238) $.

The only real root is $b = -17$, which gives $ c  = 7, a = -27$.

Answer (score 5):

If it has two equal roots, it means all three roots are real, let the double roots at $x=c$, so

$$x^3 + ax^2 + 51x + 2023=(x-c)^2(x-b)=x^3-(2c+b)x^2+(c^2+2bc)x-bc^2$$

Compare coefficients

$$-bc^2=2023\tag{1}$$
$$c^2+2bc=51\tag{2}$$
$$b+2c=-a\tag{3}$$

From (1), (2), eliminate $b$, and we get

$$0=c^3 - 51 c - 4046=(-17 + c) (238 + 17 c + c^2)$$
Therefore, $c=17, b=-7$

From (3), we get $a=-27$

Answer (score 4):

Alt. hint: $\;$ let the double root be $u$ and the third root be $v$. Then by Vieta's relations $u^2 + 2 uv = 51$ and $u^2v = -2023$. Solve the system for $u,v$, then $a = -(2u+v)$.

Answer (score 3):

This started out as an observation in the comments, but I should probably develop it further...

I found it of interest that $ \ 2023 \ $ can be factored as $ \ 7·289 \ = \ 7·17^2 \ $ (which would not be unreasonable to ask participants in a competition to find*), and that it seemed to me that someone took this as the "germ" for writing this problem.

$ ^{*}  $ I've come to believe that it is generally a good idea for someone entering a math contest to know the prime factorization of the current year (or that it's a prime -- the next one being 2027), given the predilection of problem-posers to use that number somewhere in the exam.

So if we apply the Viete relation that the constant term in $ \ x^3 + ax^2 + 51x + 2023 \ $ is the negative of the product of the zeroes $ \ -2023 \ = \ ( \ -7 \ )·( \  \pm 17 \  )^2 \ \ , \ $ we have two possibilities for $ \ a \ $ as the negative of the *sum* of these zeroes, either $ \ -( \ -7 + 2·17 \ ) \ = \ -27 \ $ or $ \ -( \ -7 + 2·[-17] \ ) \ = \ 41 \ \ . \ $  If we check these against the linear coefficient, which is the sum of the pairwise-products of the zeroes, we have either
$$ b \ \ = \ \ (-7)·17 \ +  \ (-7)·17 \ + \ 17·17 \ \ = \ \ -238 + 289 \ \ = \ \ 51 \ \ \ \text{or} $$
$$ = \ \ (-7)·(-17) \ +  \ (-7)·(-17) \ + \ (-17)·(-17) \ \ = \ \ 238 + 289 \ \ = \ \ 527 \ \ \ . $$

Only the first of these is consistent with the given polynomial, so we have $ \ a \ = \ -27 \ \ . $

In the comment, I did not intend to suggest that this was the *only* possible solution, but only that this integer solution was something the poser had in mind.  As there were already five posted answers, I was limiting this to a remark.

However, we *can* go on to show that there are no other real-number solutions.  As pointed out in other posts, if a cubic polynomial with real coefficients has a real "double zero", then all three zeroes must be real. The Rule of Signs tells us that

• for $ \ a \ > \ 0 \ \ , \ $ there are no positive and three or one negative real zeroes, and

• for $ \ a \ < \ 0 \ \ , \ $ there are two positive and one negative real zero.

[ **EDIT (6/5) --**   $ \ a \ = \ 0 \ $ is the one value that *can* be "eliminated" by the Rule of Signs, since $ \ x^3 + 51x + 2023 \ $ has no sign-changes and $ \ -x^3 - 51x + 2023 \ $ has but one, which is not consistent with the requirement of a real double zero.]

We see that the value for $ \ a \ $ shown above is consistent with this.  Using those zeroes as the "basis" for finding any others that may exist, let us write the "double zero" as $ \ r \ = \ \frac{17}{\rho} \ $ and the third zero as $ \ s \ = \ \frac{-7}{\sigma} \ \ , \ $ with $ \ \rho \ $ and $ \ \sigma \ $ being (non-zero) real numbers.  The product of the zeroes becomes
$$ -c \ \ = \ \ -2023  \ \ = \ \ \ \left(\frac{17}{\rho} \right)^2·\left( \frac{-7}{\sigma} \right) \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \rho^2·\sigma \ \ = \ \ 1 \ \ . \quad \mathbf{[ \ 1 \ ] } $$

Now the ratio $ \ \frac{b}{-c} \ $ for this monic polynomial is the ratio of the reciprocals of the zeroes, which gives us

$$ \frac{b}{-c} \ \ = \ \ \frac{51}{-2023} \ \ = \ \ -\frac{3}{119} \ \ = \ \ \frac{r^2 \ + \ 2rs}{r^2·s} \ \ = \ \ \frac{2}{r} \ + \ \frac{1}{s} $$ $$ = \ \ \frac{2·\rho}{17} \ + \ \frac{\sigma}{-7} \ \ = \ \ \frac{-14·\rho \ + \ 17·\sigma}{-119} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 14·\rho \ - \ 17·\sigma \ \ = \ \ -3 \ \ . \quad \mathbf{[ \ 2 \ ] } $$

[ **EDIT (6/5) --**  Here also, we can "reject" $ \ a \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ $ as this would imply $ \ -(2r + s) \ = \ 0 \ \Rightarrow \ s \ = \ -2r \ \Rightarrow \ b \ = \ r^2 + 2rs \ = \ -3r^2 \ = \ 51 \ \ , $ $ c \ = \ r^2·s \ = \ -2r^3 \ = \ -2023 \ \ , \ $ the first of these results not permissible, since $ \ r \ $ must be real, and the two conclusions not being mutually consistent.]

Solving these two equations simultaneously produces
$$ \sigma \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{\rho^2} \ \ \rightarrow \ \ 14·\rho \ - \ 17·\frac{1}{\rho^2} \ \ = \ \ -3  \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 14·\rho^3 \ + \ 3·\rho^2 \ - \ 17 \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ , $$
for which we know (or can readily "eyeball" that) $ \ \rho \ = \ 1 \ $ is a solution.  From this we have $ \ 14·\rho^3  +  3·\rho^2  -  17 \ = \ (\rho - 1)·(14·\rho^2 + 17·\rho + 17) \ \ , \ $ with the quadratic factor having a negative discriminant $ \ \Delta \ = \ 17^2 - 4·14·17 \ \ . $

So $ \ \rho \ = \ 1 \ \ , \ \ \sigma \ = \ 1 \ $ is the only real-valued solution for the pair of equations, making $ \ (x + 7)·(x - 17)^2 \ \ $ the sole factorization of our cubic polynomial.  Hence, $ \ a \ = \ -27 \ $ is indeed the *only* real-number value for this problem.

[This system also yields two complex-number solutions:

$$ \rho \ \ = \ \ -\frac{17}{28} \ \pm \ i·\frac{\sqrt{663}}{28} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ r \ \ = \ \ -\frac{17}{2} \ \mp \ i·\frac{\sqrt{663}}{2} \ \ , $$
$$ \sigma \ \ = \ \ -\frac{11}{34} \ \pm \ i·\sqrt{\frac{39}{17}} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ s \ \ = \ \ \frac{187}{56} \ \pm \ i·\frac{17·\sqrt{663}}{56}  $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ -r^2·s  \ \ = \ \ c \ \ = \ \ 2023 \ \ \ , \ \ \ r^2 \ + \ 2·r·s \ \ = \ \ b \ \ = \ \ 51 \ \ \ , $$
$$ a \ \ = \ \ -( \ 2r \ + \ s \ ) \ \ = \ \  -\frac{785}{56} \ \mp \ i·\frac{39·\sqrt{663}}{56} \ \ . \ ] $$

Comment: +1 As an aside: 1/ There is no need to bring in the Rule of Signs, as that isn't used anywhere in your solution. In fact, by introducing it, you now have a "gap" in your proof as you did not deal with the case of $ a = 0 $.  2/ The main crux of your solution is still the Vieta's formula system of equations, though with the benefit of guessing one of the roots.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\;P(x)=x^3+ax^2+51x+2023\,.$

It results that $\;P’(x)=3x^2+2ax+51\,.$

If $\,P(x)\,$ has $2$ equal roots $\,x_1\!=\!x_2\!=\!r\,,\,$ then $\,P(r)\!=\!P’(r)\!=\!0\,,$

hence, $\;rP’(r)-2P(r)=0\;,\;$ that is

$r^3-51r-4046=(r-17)(r^2+17r+238)=0\;,$

consequently, $\;r=17\;.$

Moreover,

$P’(17)=0\;$ $\implies$ $\;918+34a=0\;$ $\implies$ $\;a=-27\,.$

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying that last expression makes things easier to see:

$$0 = 18(1)(a)(51)(2023) - 4a^3(2023) + a^2(51)^2 - 4(1)(51)^3 - 27(1)^2(2023)^2$$

$$=-8092 a^3 + 2601 a^2 + 1857114a -111028887 = 28a^3 - 9a^2 + 6426a + 384183$$ (the final equivalence above is achieved via a division by $-289$ to make the numbers more manageable)

Now we're just solving a straightforward cubic polynomial for $a$. Factor out an $(a+27)$ to get $$28a^3 - 9a^2 + 6426a + 384183 = (a+27)(28a^2 - 765a + 14229) = 0$$

Since the second part of that factored expression (the quadratic piece) has no real roots, we can see that there is one real value of $a$ that will solve the equation, that being $a=-27$.

Comment: Given how ugly the numbers are, what motivated you to observe that we could factor out $a + 27$ (without other computational devices)?

Comment: I'll admit that it may be tricky to notice the possibility of this factorization offhand; however, it is all but necessary if one wishes to proceed to a solution using the OP's discriminant-based method (I suppose one could also use [the cubic formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html), but that seems even more unrealistic in the context of a time-constrained competition)